# Downloading resource from HP Quality Center REST API

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center

Do you know if there's a way to download the contents of test resources (files) using RESTful API?

I can see the contents of the resources:

```
http://<...>/qcbin/rest/domains/.../projects/.../resources/...:

<Field Name="storage-path">
    <Value>FileMenu.xml</Value> 
</Field>
```

But resources/.../attachments shows exception.

QC Bug? Feature?

Comment: I think it is better suited for stackoverflow

Comment: If you look in the Web Client the resource type doesn't have any attachment tab making me think there is no attachments for resources. Also in version 12 they've even scaled down on the REST api removing test storage from the documented api (still works though). We're actively trying to find a way around this but this far we've had no luck. It seems you'll have to rely on the OTA for this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is impossible in HP QC/ALM 11.0.

According to HP ALM 11.5 release notes REST web services will be improved.